# Regular Expression Match Groups

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
(.*(\d*)(-)(\d*).*)
```

It correctly matches the following string:

```
Court 19-24
```

However, the second group is empty - Group 1: Court 19-24, Group 2: [empty], Group 3: -, Group 4: 24

What is wrong with my regular expression that the second group doesn't contain 19?

Comment: Group 2 is not empty. It contains `9`.

Comment: You probably want something more like: `([^\d]+(\d+)(-)(\d+).*)` https://regex101.com/r/qcHdZD/2

Comment: @Tomalak you're right, sorry I was playing around...I've edited it back

Comment: Group 2 still contains `9`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group indexes annotated

```
(.(\d)(-)(\d*).*)
1 2   3  4
```

Not sure what you expected here?

To match `19` and `24` into two separate groups, use something like this:

```
(\d+)-(\d+)
```

To also match the court name into a group, a non-greedy star works.

```
(.*?) (\d+)-(\d+)
```

---

I bet your initial regex was more like this:

```
(.*(\d*)(-)(\d*).*)
```

This will behave closer to what you describe, because

- `.` also matches digits, i.e. `.*` will go up to the `-`, and
- `*` is not required to match anything at all, i.e. `\d*` it will happily match zero digits, causing group 2 to be empty.

Lessons:

- Don't use `*` when you expect at least *something* to be there. Prefer `+` in this case.
- Be wary of the greedy star, especially when used with the unspecific `.` it can match things you did not intend.
- You don't have to put parenthesis around *everything* in regular expressions. Only add groups around things you want to extract (i.e. "capture"), or around things you want to match/fail/repeat as one (i.e. "make atomic").

Comment: Thanks for help. Your "I bet your..." comment was spot on. Thanks again

Comment: @David Added a small summary to the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```js
let re = /.* (\d+)(-)(\d+).*/;
let str = 'Court 19-24';

var match = re.exec(str);

console.log('group 0:', match[0])
console.log('group 1:', match[1])
console.log('group 2:', match[2])
console.log('group 3:', match[3])
```